# Remove old commit preserving changes

Tags: git, github, repository, git-commit

I started editing a project downloaded from a [glitch](https://glitch.com/) repository I played around for a little bit. A lot of automatic commits were done before I downloaded the project and continued editing it locally. The issue is that the automatic commits probably contain sensitive information (like my phone number or a url with an access token) I don't want showing up on the repository, plus it makes the project look a bit messy.

I want to keep `749bcc4` and later and delete `cd1ee76` and earlier commits from the repo without affecting the newer ones.

My `git log` now looks like this:

```
<17 more recent commits made by me>
4dea670 (Supress logs during tests, 2022-06-04)
8915b33 (Webhook subsciption tests, 2022-06-04)
f189b0b (Functioning test template with chai-http added, 2022-06-04)
749bcc4 (Replies automatically to every message received, 2022-06-04) <-- I pickup the project and get serious about it
cd1ee76 (⛩ Checkpoint ./app.js:44684210/652, 2022-05-12) <-- Automatic checkpoint (I am technically not the author of these)
b8531dc ( Checkpoint ./README.md:44684210/2364 ./app.js:44684210/12304, 2022-05-11)
a92f72a (☃️ Checkpoint ./package.json:44684210/231 ./app.js:44684210/95 ./README.md:44684210/164, 2022-05-11)
11bb69b ( Checkpoint ./app.js:44684210/242, 2022-05-11)
8482190 (❣️ Checkpoint ./README.md:44684210/16, 2022-05-11)
7123b4c (⛹ Checkpoint ./package.json:44684210/3241, 2022-05-11)
<And like 50 more checkpoint commits>
```

Is there any way to remove them and then forcing a push to the remote repo? I am working alone with that remote (that might change soon) so the push shouldn't be problematic for anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: no and yes.  You will need to get assistance from GitHub admins.

#### Long

You *can* "edit history" in a Git repository—but the way this works is by *copying* (some or all of) the old commits to new-and-improved commits, and all *subsequent* commits must then *also* be copied.  If you're working alone, there's no one else who will have any problems with this "copy/rework the old commits then change over to use the new improved ones", so you're safe to `git push --force`.  But you specifically mention GitHub, and here the fact that you're making *new* commits matters.

Let's look at how Git works internally here:

- Each commit is numbered, with a number unique to that one particular commit.  (Git calls this a *hash ID* or *object ID*.  Every commit in every repository gets a *unique* number.  Not "mostly unique", not "kind of unique", but *unique*.  That's how two Gits, when they meet and greet each other with `git push` or `git fetch`, figure out which commits they have that the other doesn't; they use this information to feed commits from the sender to the receiver, without re-feeding things the receiver already has.)
- Every commit stores two things: its snapshot-of-files, and some metadata, or information about the commit itself.  These are *completely read only:* no part of any commit can ever be changed (which is how the hash ID trick works).  The metadata include things like your name and email address (from `user.name` and `user.email`), but also include the raw hash ID(s) of some earlier commit(s).

The commits (and other supporting objects) are stored in a big all-objects database, where Git can look them up.  To *find* an object *in* this database, Git *needs* the hash ID.  So if Git didn't have a *second* database, we'd all have to memorize our hash IDs (e.g., `749bcc4` is one of yours, but this is an *abbreviated* one and we might have to memorize the full 40 characters).

We only need to save the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain, because Git stores, in each commit's metadata, the hash ID of the *previous* commit in that chain.  That is, if you're working on branch `main`, Git has a name—in this case `main`—that holds the hash ID *of* the last commit in the chain.  We say that this name *points to* the last (or *tip*) commit.  That commit contains the hash ID of the second-to-last commit, which contains the hash ID of the third-to-last commit, and so on:

```
... <-[third-to-last]  <-[second-to-last]  <-[last]   <--main
```

Since each commit *has* a unique hash ID, all we have to do is feed Git any one of these hash IDs and Git can retrieve the commit.  But we don't have to memorize all of them, or even the last one, because the *name* `main` holds the last one.  So we can tell Git: *look up the name `main`, get the hash ID, and get the commit*.  Git does so and finds the last commit, which has inside it the hash ID of the previous commit.  Git can look that up and find the commit, which has inside it the hash ID of the previous commit ... and so on, forever backwards, one commit at a time, until Git gets to the *first* commit ever.  That one has *no* previous hash ID (because it can't, there is no previous commit) and so here it all finally stops.

To make a new commit, we "check out" the branch, do the usual stuff, run and `git commit`.  Git builds up the snapshot and metadata and sets up the new commit so that it will point backwards to what is, right now, the last commit, whose hash ID is in the name.  Then Git writes this out, freezing it for all time.  That allocates a new unique hash ID, and the new commit just made *is* the last commit in the chain, so Git now writes that hash ID into the *name* `main`—and voila, the picture remains the same, except now there's a new "last" commit.

#### With the above in mind, history rewriting becomes simple(ish)

Let's say we have a chain of commits that we'll draw like this, using single uppercase letters to stand in for commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- main
```

(I've gotten lazy about the arrows, but the ones from commit to commit still point backwards: `J` to `I`, `I` to `H`, and so on.)  Let's say there's something we don't like *about* commit `H`, whether it's in the snapshot, the metadata, or both.  To fix it, we have Git *check out* commit `G`, by its raw hash ID—using a tool like `git rebase` so *we* don't have to cut and paste too many hash IDs; that's a recipe for error—which gives us this:

```
          H--I--J   <-- main
         /
...--F--G   <-- temporary-branch (HEAD)
```

Using the temporary branch, we make a new and improved commit that *replaces* `H`, which we might as well call `H'`:

```
          H--I--J   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--H'  <-- temporary-branch (HEAD)
```

Everything was fine with commits `I-J` so we copy them (or let `git rebase` do it, which `git rebase` does using `git cherry-pick`).  We can't *alter* commit `I`: we can't change *anything* about *any* commit.  But we can easily make a *new* commit, `I'`, that points to `H'` instead of `H`:

```
          H--I--J   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--H'-I'  <-- temporary-branch (HEAD)
```

We do the same for `J`:

```
          H--I--J   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--H'-I'-J'  <-- temporary-branch (HEAD)
```

and now we use the fact that *people* find commits by *name:* we tell Git to wrestle the name `main` around so that instead of pointing to `J`, it points to `J'`.  We switch back to branch `main` and delete the temporary *name* so that we have:

```
          H--I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--F--G--H'-I'-J'  <-- main (HEAD)
```

As long as we look up commits by *name*, we'll never *see* the old ones.

(The mechanism you'll probably want to use, to get the new-and-improved commits, is `git rebase --interactive` which lets you use *squash* and/or *fixup* commands to combine commits.  Squashing a bunch of "checkpoint" commits together effectively replaces that whole series of checkpoint commits with a single commit that produces the same *final result*.)

#### But what happens to the old commits?

The key to your particular problem comes in here: we're using the new and improved commits, having abandoned the old commits.  But they still exist.  *Git* has a mechanism—actually a whole complicated Rube-Goldberg-esque series of mechanisms—by which an unused, abandoned commit is *eventually* removed for real (called "pruning" and/or "garbage collection" depending on which level of the Goldberg machinery you want to work with).  The commits fall away some time after 30 to 90 days.  Exactly when, we don't control, unless we get deep enough into the machinery using `git gc` for instance (GC stands for Garbage Collection, although I sometimes call it the Grim <s>Reaper</s> Collector, or in this case the Goldberg Collector).  Once Git has garbage-collected the abandoned commits, they're *really gone*—from *this copy of the repository*, that is.

The way Git works overall, *everyone* has a *full copy* of *all* commits.  So if someone else, in some *other* Git repository, has the "bad" commits that you want gone ... well, now we're getting into the danger territory.

In this case, GitHub is the "other Git".  They have a copy of your repository.  You will use `git push --force` or equivalent to send them your `H'-I'-J'` new commits and then *command* them to set their `main` to point to `J'` instead of `J`, so that their repository will look exactly like yours:

```
          H--I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--F--G--H'-I'-J'  <-- main (HEAD)
```

You now cross fingers and hope that some time after 30 to 90 days, *GitHub* will garbage-collect the `H-I-J` sequence.  But if you *know the hash ID*, you can feed that hash ID directly to software over on GitHub, and thereby access and read those commits.

#### GitHub don't throw out the garbage

Now we hit the big snag: while you made GitHub's repository abandon commit `J`, they *never take out the trash*, as it were.  They never garbage-collect abandoned commits.  This isn't a *promise*, and maybe someday they will do it.  Maybe someday in the past they did do it.  It's just a state-of-affairs that we see today: right now they don't.  (This all has to do with GitHub's "fork" mechanism; if a repository has never been forked, GitHub *could* GC it safely, but if it has forks, they'd have to create a lot of really complicated new Rube Goldberg machinery.)

What this means is that if someone "out there" has memorized, or can guess, a raw hash ID for the commits you'd *like* GitHub to throw out, that someone *can* find your old abandoned commits over on GitHub.  They *can* read them and thereby see the things you wish they couldn't.

GitHub admins *can* go into the GitHub storage and force these abandoned commits to be GC-ed for real.  Having them do that will get rid of the commits from the GitHub copy.  If nobody else has made a copy of the GitHub copy in the meantime, *then* your abandoned commits are gone from every copy in the universe, and *then* you're safe.

(This is why the general rule is that if some secret has ever been published on GitHub, we should just assume that everyone knows it now.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks a lot for taking the time to write it. The github problem could be solved by creating a new remote repository and deleting/archiving/keeping private the older repo, right? If I manage to get rid of the bad commits locally and they don't exist anymore, I could push that local copy of my repo to a new github remote and everything would be fine I suppose, am I right?
I will try in the meantime to do the rebase trick.

Comment: By the way, the to-be-garbage-collected local commits (if they don't exist in the remote), don't get pushed, right? Just like you push only one branch at the time and a newly created branch doesn't get published until it gets explicitly pushed, I suppose?

Comment: `git rebase -i` is an excellent tool. I squashed all the commits from the first (a checkpoint) to the last before mine running `git rebase -i <first ever commit>` and replacing `pick` by `squash` on all the lines from the second to the one before mine. Thank you very much for your help and background explanation

Comment: I was offline all day yesterday (and much of today). To address the comments, more or less in order: (1) yes, if nobody has access to the "bad" repo you should be OK.. (2) Yes, `git push` only sends the *accessible* commits that you have that they don't. (3) good :-)